# How to read members of HttpHandlers in Web.config

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, web-config

Is it possible to read the httpHandler members, which are defined in web.config in C# code file.  I would like to create a list of the values which are read.

Thanks and regards
Rithesh

Answer (score 0):

you can read any key/value from Web.Config.

Try these lines of code:

```
NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("YOUR_SECTION_NAME_HERE");
string data = section["YOUR_KEY"];
```

Hope it helps.